# How can I write a rule that finds a number using integer/1?

Tags: prolog

I am writing a rule that is looking for a particular integer. I assumed I can write something like this

```
find_number(X):-
    integer(X),
    X > 1, X < 5.
```

Then expect the result of a query to `integer(X)` to result in `X=2, X=3, X=4, false.` Instead, I just get a `false` result. The only way I found to write this rule is to use `numlist/3` like so

```
find_number(X):-
    numlist(2, 4, NumList),
    member(X, NumList).
```

Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 4):

Your reasoning would be **perfectly valid** *iff* `integer/1` were an actual **relation** that satisfies basic logical properties.

For example, in classical logic, a unary predicate P satisfies the following property:

> **If** P(σ(T)) is satisfiable for any substitution σ and term T, **then** P(T) is *also* satisfiable.

This seems completely obvious and of course *holds* also for all **pure** predicates in Prolog.

The problem is that `integer/1` is **not** a pure relation.

In particular, we have for example:

```
?- integer(3).
true.
```

Yet the following **more general** query *fails*:

```
?- integer(X).
false.
```

*Is there any integer?* **No.**

Believe it or not, that's how `integer/1` actually works.

Clearly, something seems not quite right for such predicates, and so there are **better alternatives** in all widely used modern Prolog systems. I strongly recommend you use such alternatives instead, to get the most out of Prolog.

For the case of *integers*, I recommend you check out **CLP(FD) constraints** ([clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)).

For example, in GNU Prolog, your code could look like this:

```
good_number(X) :-
        X #> 1,
        X #< 5.
```

With the following queries and answers:

```
| ?- good_number(X).
X = _#2(2..4)

| ?- good_number(X), fd_labeling([X]).
X = 2 ? ;
X = 3 ? ;
X = 4
```

This works exactly as we expect a relation to work! I have taken the liberty to change the name such that it makes sense also in more specific cases, where there is *nothing left to "find"*:

```
| ?- good_number(3).
yes
```

Depending on your Prolog system, you may have to import a library to use such more declarative features. See also [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, but I think that @coder gave a more concise one: `integer/1` fails on uninstantiated variables.

Comment: Yes, that's more concise. In addition, I want you to know that such predicates are *not* true relations. This makes them extremely hard to understand, and especially for beginners, I can only recommend to avoid them and use more declarative methods instead. By using CLP(FD) constraints, you will be able to reason logically about your programs.

Answer (score 1):

You get only false because `integer/1` tests if the input is an integer and if it is it succeeds else if it is not an integer or if it is a variable that is not instantiated as in your case, then it fails.

You could use `between/2` built in predicate:

```
find_number(X):-between(2,4,X).
```

This will return:

```
?- find_number(X).
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4.
```